# Kubernetes: How to move a pod to another node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a cluster with 2 nodes with local storage, I want to move a pod and its volume from node 1 to node 2, because the disk of node 1 is a little full. thanks

Comment: I guess the term you're looking for is called, volume snapshot.

Comment: @KamolHasan thanks for your comment, I have edited the question title, I need to move the pod to another node, but I didn't set up a shared storage!